# Same filename with a different extension

Tags: windows, filenames, file-extension

I have a fairly large collection of music, some of which I have ripped at different times with different software.  Through all my updates and additions to my collection, I have ended up with a mixture of file formats.

Through the magic of [MusicBrainz](http://musicbrainz.org/), I have organized all my music into a Artist/Album/Title.fmt directory structure.  What I want is to find files where Artist/Album/Title are the same, but .fmt (.mp3, .ogg, .wma, etc) is different.  Basically, I want to get a list of duplicate songs that differ only by file extension.

If it makes a difference, I'm on Windows 7.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something obvious, don't you already see this list if you open the specific folder? If you sort by file name, you should see all the files with same name but different extension one after the other.

Comment: That would be OK if it was a single folder with a few files.  However, the size of the collection would make that long, drawn out, and tedious.  I'm seeking a more automated method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they were all iTunes-compatible formats, [it could do it for you](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2905), but I suspect they're not.

Comment: Unfortunately iTunes doesn't (didn't?) handle Ogg Vorbis.  I'll have to investigate if this has changed.

Answer (score 0):

See this, not sure if it works across all audio formats
http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-find-and-remove-duplicate-audio-files/

another
http://skvnet.blogspot.com/2008/01/find-duplicate-mp3-ogg-wma-and-flac.html

Google is your friend
http://www.google.com/#hl=en&source=hp&q=duplicate+audio+file+finder&aq=f&aqi=g1&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=CXbmctnR-TN2_O5HCNrjQsLQEAAAAqgQFT9DpAzs&pbx=1&fp=7db4f7af4a13aa89

.